# The great OpenERP 7 directory structure mystery

Tags: centos, odoo

I am currently deploying OpenERP 7 on a CentOS 6.4 machine.
I'm virtualizing the whole thing so that I can backup the whole system if I mess up.

Everything seems to be fine, I changed my models, my views, but it's been 2 days I've been banging my head against a seemingly impossible problem.

My deployment is for a book factory, so the product needed to be customized (number of pages, binding type , and so forth...)

In the new product view, I need something that can sum to fields x_colorpages and x_bwpages to populate a third field: x_totalpages. Easy huh?

I've got my XML , product.normal.form view based on the product.poduct object

When I change the value in "x_paginecolori" or "xpagineBN" it should automatically trigger the onchange function.

So I went in the product module code and coded my cal_change_event

In the python file product.py located in: 
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130524_231019-py2.6.egg/openerp/addons/account/product.py

```
def cal_change_event(self, cr, uid, ids, x_PagineColori, x_PagineBN):
      res = {}
      sum = 0
if not  x_PagineColori: 
    return {}
else if not x_PagineBN:
    return {}
else:
    sum = x_PagineColori + x_PagineBN
    res={'x_pagine':sum }
    return {'value':res}
```

NO matter what i do , the onchange event will allways trigger a warning popup:

**File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130524_231019-py2.6.egg/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 185, in execute_cr
    return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
AttributeError: 'product.product' object has no attribute 'cal_change_event'**

It seems to me that the function is not seen, where should I put it?
How can Product.Product not have this attribute if I placed it in the class inside  product.py?

I grep'd the whole CENTOS installation in search for multiple instances of openerp , or to see if I missed something about product.py

It seems that the product.py is not the right file, even if I erase other On_change functions, nothing bad really happens.
But the directory must be right, because the error log gives me that same location in the debug popup window.

Should I be building a custom module fron scratch to make this work? Is it forbidden somehow to modify the standard product module?

Thanks in advance for any insight, my brain is defaulting on this one.

here is my Xml:

```
            <?xml version="1.0"?>
                <form string="Product" version="7.0">
                                        <sheet>    
            <div>
                             <label for="x_partner2" string="Cliente Referente del prodotto"/>
                                 <field name="x_partner2" />
                                    </div>
                                        <field name="image_medium" widget="image" class="oe_avatar oe_left"/>
                                        <div class="oe_title">
                                            <div class="oe_edit_only">
                                                <label for="name" string="Product Name"/>
                                            </div>
                                            <h1>
                                                <field name="name"/>
                                            </h1>
                                            <label for="categ_id" class="oe_edit_only"/>
                                            <h2><field name="categ_id"/></h2>
                                            <div name="options" groups="base.group_user">
                                                <field name="sale_ok"/>
                                                <label for="sale_ok"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="oe_right oe_button_box" name="buttons">
                                        </div>
                                        <notebook>
                  <page string="Information">
                                                <group>
                                                    <group>
                                                        <field name="type"/>
                                                        <field name="uom_id" on_change="onchange_uom(uom_id,uom_po_id)" groups="product.group_uom"/>
                                                        <field name="list_price"/>
                                                    </group>
                                                    <group>
                                                        <field name="default_code"/>
                                                        <label for="ean13"/>
                                                        <div name="ean">
                                                            <field name="ean13" placeholder="e.g. 5901234123457"/>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </group>
                                                    <group>
                                                        <field groups="product.group_product_variant" name="variants"/>
                                                        <field name="price_margin" groups="product.group_product_variant"/>
                                                        <field name="price_extra" groups="product.group_product_variant"/>
                                                    </group>
                                                </group>
                                                <field name="description" placeholder="describe the product characteristics..."/>
                            </page>
                  <page string="Dati del volume Universal Book">
                <group>
                <group>
                                            <field name="x_DataCreazione" />
                                                        <field name="x_DataUltimaModifica" />
                                        <field name="x_Autore" />
                                                        <field name="x_Larghezza"/>
                                         <field name="x_Altezza" />
                                         <field name="x_Dorso"/>
                                                 <field name="x_Rilegatura" />
                 <field name="x_volumiformati" />

                </group>
                </group>
                <group>
                                                 <field name="x_PagineColori"  on_change="cal_change_event(x_PagineColori,x_PagineBN)" />
                                                 <field name="x_PagineBN"  on_change="cal_change_event(x_PagineColori,x_PagineBN)" />
                                                 <field name="x_pagine" />
                </group>
                <group>
                                                 <field name="x_prezzo" />
                </group>
                </page>

                 <page string="Copertina">
                <group>
                <group>
                <field name="x_TipoCartaCopertina"/>
                <field name="x_TipoStampaCopertina"/>
                                      <field name="x_TipoFFR"/>
                                                 <field name="x_PlastificazioneCopertina" />
                                                 <field name="x_NumeroCopertinePerPagina" />
                </group>
                <group>
                <field name="x_TipoCartaSovracopertina"/>
                <field name="x_TipoStampaScopertina"/>
                 <field name="x_TipoFFRSovracopertina"/>
                 <field name="x_PlastificazioneSovracopertina"/>
                </group>
                </group>
                <label for="x_aletta" string="Libro con alette?"/>
                 <field name="x_aletta" />
                <label for="x_Note" string="Note"/>
                                                 <field name="x_Note" />
                                            </page>
                <page string="Margini">
                <group>
                 <field name="x_pagriferimento"/>
                 <field name="x_MargineDestro"/>
                 <field name="x_MargineDestro"/>
                <field name="x_MargineInferiore" />
                <field name="x_MargSinistro" />
                <field name="x_MargineSuperiore"/>
                <field name="x_RiferimentoLIFRE" />
                <field name="x_MergineSuperioreLIFRE" />
                <field name="x_MargineInferioreLIFRE" />
                </group>
                </page>
                                            <page string="Procurements" groups="base.group_user">
                                                <group name="procurement">
                                                    <group name="general">
                                                        <field name="cost_method" groups="product.group_costing_method"/>
                                                        <field name="standard_price" attrs="{'readonly':[('cost_method','=','average')]}"/>
                                                    </group>
                                                    <group name="procurement_uom" groups="product.group_uom" string="Purchase">
                                                        <field name="uom_po_id"/>
                                                    </group>
                                                </group>
                                                <separator string="Description for Suppliers"/>
                                                <field name="description_purchase" placeholder="This note will be displayed on requests for quotation..."/>
                                            </page>
                                            <page string="Inventory" groups="base.group_user">
                                                <group name="inventory">
                                                    <group name="status" string="Status">
                                                        <field name="state"/>
                                                        <field name="product_manager"/>
                                                    </group>
                                                    <group name="Weights" groups="product.group_stock_packaging" string="Weights">
                                                        <field digits="(14, 3)" name="volume" attrs="{'readonly':[('type','=','service')]}"/>
                                                        <field name="weight" attrs="{'readonly':[('type','=','service')]}"/>
                                                        <field name="weight_net" attrs="{'readonly':[('type','=','service')]}"/>
                                                    </group>
                                                </group>
                                            </page>
                                            <page string="Sales" attrs="{'invisible':[('sale_ok','=',False)]}">
                                                <group name="sale">
                                                    <group string="Sale Conditions">
                                                        <label for="warranty"/>
                                                        <div>
                                                            <field name="warranty" class="oe_inline"/> months
                                                        </div>
                                                    </group>
                                                    <group groups="product.group_uos" string="Unit of Measure">
                                                        <field name="uos_id"/>
                                                        <field name="uos_coeff"/>
                                                        <field name="mes_type"/>
                                                    </group>
                                                </group>
                                                <field name="packaging" groups="product.group_stock_packaging">
                                                    <form string="Packaging" version="7.0">
                                                        <group col="4">
                                                            <field name="ean"/>
                                                            <field name="sequence" invisible="1"/>
                                                            <newline/>
                                                            <field name="qty"/>
                                                            <field name="ul"/>
                                                            <field name="weight_ul"/>
                                                            <separator colspan="4" string="Palletization"/>
                                                            <field name="ul_qty"/>
                                                            <field name="rows"/>
                                                            <field name="weight"/>
                                                            <separator colspan="4" string="Pallet Dimension"/>
                                                            <field name="height"/>
                                                            <field name="width"/>
                                                            <field name="length"/>
                                                        </group>
                                                        <separator colspan="4" string="Description"/>
                                                        <field name="name"/>
                                                    </form>
                                                </field>
                                                <separator string="Description for Quotations"/>
                                                <field name="description_sale" placeholder="note to be displayed on quotations..."/>
                                            </page>
                                        </notebook>
                                    </sheet>
                                    <div class="oe_chatter">
                                        <field name="message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers"/>
                                        <field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread"/>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

Comment: Hi, from your XML I couldn't see any onchange methods calls that are related to the three fields you've mentioned.

Comment: I'm sorry , i'll be posting the correct code this evening. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Just posted the real XML, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: That's all right. The XML looks fine now, one thing to mention is that the cal_change_event() method should have a parameter named context (you could look at other onchange methods). But this is not related to the error message you got and I have no idea why did it happen. I'd recommend to write a module from scratch, there are tutorials on the OpenERP official website.

Comment: I'll go the new module route, as you suggested. I've spent too long on this, trying to personalize standard product.product object. Also, Updating the module as you suggested reverts my standard product module to default. I'll be posting my findings, perhaps this thread can be useful for beginners that want javascript triggers calling functions in their views.

Answer (score 0):

It's not forbidden to modify the standard modules, but it is generally recommended to write your own modules to extend OpenERP.

I don't know how much experience you've got with OpenERP (if you are new to OpenERP, the problem could be caused by very simple mistakes), so forgive me for assuming you are a newbie.

1. Have you restarted OpenERP and reinstalled the product module?
2. Is the cal_change_event() method defined in a class whose _name = "product.product" ?
3. Could you post your XML code? The problem could be nothing to do with your Python code.

Comment: 1. I have restarted openERP but not reinstalled the product module. I assumed changing the code and restarting  was enough.

Comment: 2. the cal_change_event is in the product.product class

Comment: 3. I'll add my XML to the post

Comment: Just put my files on a windows deployment. Everything works fine! Any Ideas on what could be wrong in CENTOS?

Answer (score 0):

All the code here works FINE. The problem seemed to be my CENTOS install.
This code works correctly on WINDOWS and a new XUBUNTU Machine I just made.
Unfortunately the reason *why* it didn't work in CentOS still eludes me.
I'm closing this topic, hopefully the code pf my .XML and .PY  can be a useful template for all those who wish to have personalized fields in their products and have them interactively change. thanks Wenshan for your assistance, as you noticed in the beginning, nothing was wrong with the code.